# page not found after migrating drupal 7 to dev version same server using drush archive-restore

Tags: 7, drush

I have tried twice over to migrate a production site to a development version using a different database and although the files are all there and the database is also there I just keep getting a 'Page not found' when browsing to the dev version. I have checked my settings.php file which is pointing to the correct database too.

Here is a list of the process I used:

`drush archive-restore /home/username/drush-backups/archive-dump/20120821113939/hampstea_db.20120821_113946.tar.gz default --destination=./hamp-dev --db-url=mysql://username:password@localhost/db_name`

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hard to debug from here, but as a first step I would recommend storing your dev site in a folder that is outside of your production site's Drupal root. Make an entirely new ghost conf file for the dev site, or add an alias in your production ghost conf: `alias hamp-dev /path/to/dev`; then you could still get to your dev site via `http://production/hamp-dev`.  Note that you will also need a <Directory /path/to/dev> that mirrors the config for your production site's Drupal root.

Comment: That makes sense but the site is hosted on shared hosting and I don't think I have permissions to do this. I want to show client dev work before putting it on production site so need to use remote server as opposed to local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just struck me; don't know why I missed it before.  Rather than using archive-restore, use the [Drupal multisite](http://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site) feature to make both your dev and prod site use the same codebase.  Make http://mysite.com and http://dev.mysite.com point to the same IP address.  If your ISP will serve up the same document root from both of these names, then you can follow the instructions on the aforementioned page to serve content from a different database based on the domain requested.  If you can't do this, you need better hosting! There's a lot of good and inexpensive plans out there.

As an aside, I like to use the [Environment indicator](http://drupal.org/project/environment_indicator) module to keep track visually of which site I am looking at.

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't set up a multisite on shared webhosting with Site 5. I had to use a subdomain within the drupal root directory. I manually copied the files over and pointed to new database, which all worked. My issue was really getting the drush archive-restore to work but alas could not get it to somehow. I did an archive restore on my local server and that did work however. I will definitely check out Environment indicator. Thanks for all the suggestions and time to reply.  :)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of questions:

1. Are you creating that dev site as a root subfolder of the production site?
2. If yes, do you get a page not found on the production site OR on the server?

This might be an issue with .htaccess; if you just added dev site to the root of your production website, you might need to add a rule to exclude "/dev".

I think adding this before rewrite conditions for the production site would work:

```
RewriteRule ^(dev).* - [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. To answer your questions: 1. Yes, the dev site is a root subfolder of the production site. 2. The production site works fine but when navigating to dev site ie. www.sitename.com/dev I get the 'page not found' error. I have created dev versions of other sites using backup and migrate and other methods without it posing a problem before. Its just since I tried the archive-restore that this cropped up. Should I add that ReswriteRule to htaccess on production site? thanks again

Comment: I added that line before Rewrite conditions in .htaccess of production site and it hasn't made a difference. I haven't had to do this with other sites I've had a dev version of on the same server before. I may just do the manual method for migrating as I know it works. If you have any other suggestions I would be v grateful.

Answer (score 0):

The dev site is installed in a subfolder and probably has clean urls enabled.

Just edit .htaccess of the *dev* site and set RewriteBase /dev

Comment: Thanks, made no difference though. I will just start from the top again as I have done dev version on same server before and it worked.